# Synchronous vs. Asynchronous Sockets question

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I have a simple interface between two systems using sockets.
The external system "SENDER" sends text messages (containing XML) intermittently 24x7.
My "RECEIVER" service just sits and listens on a specific port and when a complete message is received, writes the received message data to a file.

No other processes will use this dedicated port.

For a simple, dedicated, 1:1 send-receive pairing like this, is there any reason to use an asynchronous sockets interface?  The synchronous code was trivial, but if there is a good reason to use asynchronous logic, I would consider re-implementing the interface in that manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For a simple, dedicated, 1:1 send-receive pairing like this, is there any reason to use an asynchronous sockets interface?

No.  Having a dedicated thread for the listener and a dedicated thread for each TCP socket accepted is fine, so long as you have only a few hundred concurrent TCP sessions.